# Laptop lagging, can't shut down

Tags: windows, laptop, lag

My laptop has this problem where after a couple of hours it starts lagging to the point that its unusable. When I try to restart it, it just hangs on the "Restarting" screen. I always end up hard resetting it.

It's an [Asus N53SN](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks/Multimedia_Entertainment/N53SN/#specifications) running Windows 8 at the moment. The problem started a couple months ago, when I was still running Windows 7.

Things I've done:

1. Re-install drivers
2. Format and re-install Windows 7
3. Sent it in to Asus, they reformatted it, re-installed Windows 7 and new drivers (That was useless, and I'm out of warranty now)
4. Format and install Windows 8

Comment: Have you tried to spirit away dirt from the inside part of your laptop (Clean Cooler) ??

Comment: My experience with Asus is very good, as this went wrong during warranty (which they have on record) and isn't fixed they may still help you out.

Comment: So on a **completely clean** installation of Windows 8 with absolutely no custom software at all, just rebooting the machine hangs and you have to hard reset it? And what programs do you run when it becomes "slow and unusable"? Does it happen if you just run a simple web browser?

Comment: I haven't tried to clean the inside, I'll try that this weekend. As for the install, yes it was a clean install, and it happens after a couple of hours of using. That eliminates software right?

Answer (score 0):

When you reinstalled windows, did you immediately protect it with antivirus? It sounds like you have two antivirus products running along side each other. That will give this problem. In my experience, the unlikely combination of Kaspersky and Windows Defender can do this, along with the more likely combinations like AVG and Norton. If it was hard drive failure, I'd expect this behavior to happen immediately.

Comment: Currently the only antivirus I have running is the built in antivirus in Windows 8, which is Windows Defender.

Comment: In which case I don't know what's causing your problem without looking at it myself. If there were less possibilities that cause poor performance, it'd be a bit easier to narrow down, but the list is endless.